# JSON -> Apex Custom Class conversion issue

Tags: apex, json

Im attempting to deserialize a JSON string into a custom apex class but Im getting a NULL value back from one particular node "transaction". Any ideas why its not translating from "transaction" to "transaction_Z"? (note: all the data included below is dummy data, not a real person)

```
String jsondata = '{"guid":"ABCXYZ123","payload":{"additionalPolicyHolders":[{"email":"lisa@example.com","firstName":"Lisa","lastName":"Hugo","primaryPhone":"(913) 555-7411"}],"animals":[{"ageIsUnderSeven":false,"ageIsUnderSevenDate":"2011-12-21T03:15:22.955688+00:00","altered":"Yes","animalId":"M7","birthdate":"2008-09-13T00:00:00","diagnoses":[{"examDate":"2018-12-20T06:00:00+00:00","medicalConditionDuration":"Chronic","medicalConditionId":"94a298d9-04cc-f4a8-2eef-28ef7abbfdee","medicalConditionResolutionDate":null,"notes":null,"veterinarianId":"613dfd1b-6c79-4f4c-5b58-33aa87f6b38b"}],"gender":"Male","microchipNumber":"MC99887","name":"Looper","primaryBreedId":"39d60923-8963-7b85-dc73-f53ae63d659c","primaryColorId":"50f29d68-44a1-c7ca-6b35-fdf45bf5e4d0","profilePhoto":null,"secondaryBreedId":"75a1d389-7cfe-842e-c939-d91d1b8f2ba1","secondaryColorId":"8c0b2481-3f69-2239-e899-ead97857cec6","species":"Cat","medicalFiles":[{"url":"https://petmedicalinternal.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/314a94d4-18f4-409c-a039-0a3e41f8dd51.txt","filename":"sample file 1.txt","sizeInBytes":13},{"url":"https://petmedicalinternal.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/fa21763b-bd31-476f-8d37-d086cbabf9a4.pdf","filename":"sample file 2.pdf","sizeInBytes":3028}]}],"billingAddress":{"addressLine1":"45 W 876th St","addressLine2":"Apt 2","city":"Las Vegas","state":"NV","zip":"88901"},"deviceId":"5200c61e46684575","email":"larry@example.com","firstName":"Larry","isAdvancePremiumPaymentAccepted":true,"isContactEmailAccepted":true,"isESignConsentAccepted":true,"isPreexistingConditionCoverageAccepted":true,"lastName":"Pippon","leadSource":"Agent App","organizationId":"94b70a81-c674-c83d-ad72-0b37331364af","policyTermId":"126a4914-86c7-44f3-f61e-fd830020d4ad","primaryAddress":{"addressLine1":"45 W 876th St","addressLine2":"Apt 2","city":"Las Vegas","state":"NV","zip":"88901"},"primaryPhone":"(913) 555-1343","secondaryPhone":"(913) 555-6236","signature":{},"transaction":"amount":"35.99","amountAuthorized":"35.99","authCode":"123456","avsResponse":"N","customerVaultId":"426809411","cvvResponse":"N","orderId":"abc","response":"1","responseCode":"100","responseText":"SUCCESS","transactionId":"bbb","type":"auth"}}}';


Class_LeadExport exportClass = (Class_LeadExport)JSON.deserialize(String.valueOf(jsondata), Class_LeadExport.class);
system.debug('exportClass--->'+exportClass.payload.transaction_Z);
```

Custom Apex Class

```
public class Class_LeadExport {

    public class BillingAddress {
        public String addressLine1 {get;set;} 
        public String addressLine2 {get;set;} 
        public String city {get;set;} 
        public String state {get;set;} 
        public String zip {get;set;} 

        public BillingAddress(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'addressLine1') {
                            addressLine1 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'addressLine2') {
                            addressLine2 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'city') {
                            city = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'state') {
                            state = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'zip') {
                            zip = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'BillingAddress consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class AdditionalPolicyHolders {
        public String email {get;set;} 
        public String firstName {get;set;} 
        public String lastName {get;set;} 
        public String primaryPhone {get;set;} 

        public AdditionalPolicyHolders(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'email') {
                            email = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'firstName') {
                            firstName = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'lastName') {
                            lastName = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'primaryPhone') {
                            primaryPhone = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'AdditionalPolicyHolders consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Animals {
        public Boolean ageIsUnderSeven {get;set;} 
        public String ageIsUnderSevenDate {get;set;} 
        public String altered {get;set;} 
        public String animalId {get;set;} 
        public String birthdate {get;set;} 
        public List<Diagnoses> diagnoses {get;set;} 
        public String gender {get;set;} 
        public String microchipNumber {get;set;} 
        public String name {get;set;} 
        public String primaryBreedId {get;set;} 
        public String primaryColorId {get;set;} 
        public ProfilePhoto profilePhoto {get;set;} 
        public String secondaryBreedId {get;set;} 
        public String secondaryColorId {get;set;} 
        public String species {get;set;} 
        public List<MedicalFiles> medicalFiles {get;set;} 

        public Animals(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'ageIsUnderSeven') {
                            ageIsUnderSeven = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else if (text == 'ageIsUnderSevenDate') {
                            ageIsUnderSevenDate = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'altered') {
                            altered = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'animalId') {
                            animalId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'birthdate') {
                            birthdate = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'diagnoses') {
                            diagnoses = arrayOfDiagnoses(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'gender') {
                            gender = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'microchipNumber') {
                            microchipNumber = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'name') {
                            name = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'primaryBreedId') {
                            primaryBreedId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'primaryColorId') {
                            primaryColorId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'profilePhoto') {
                            profilePhoto = new ProfilePhoto(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'secondaryBreedId') {
                            secondaryBreedId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'secondaryColorId') {
                            secondaryColorId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'species') {
                            species = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'medicalFiles') {
                            medicalFiles = arrayOfMedicalFiles(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Animals consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MedicalFiles {
        public String url {get;set;} 
        public String filename {get;set;} 
        public Integer sizeInBytes {get;set;} 

        public MedicalFiles(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'url') {
                            url = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'filename') {
                            filename = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'sizeInBytes') {
                            sizeInBytes = parser.getIntegerValue();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'MedicalFiles consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Signature {
        public String bytes {get;set;} 
        public String contentType {get;set;} 
        public String filename {get;set;} 

        public Signature(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'bytes') {
                            bytes = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'contentType') {
                            contentType = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'filename') {
                            filename = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Signature consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ProfilePhoto {
        public String bytes {get;set;} 
        public String contentType {get;set;} 
        public String filename {get;set;} 

        public ProfilePhoto(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'bytes') {
                            bytes = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'contentType') {
                            contentType = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'filename') {
                            filename = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'ProfilePhoto consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Payload {
        public List<AdditionalPolicyHolders> additionalPolicyHolders {get;set;} 
        public List<Animals> animals {get;set;} 
        public BillingAddress billingAddress {get;set;} 
        public String deviceId {get;set;} 
        public String email {get;set;} 
        public String firstName {get;set;} 
        public Boolean isAdvancePremiumPaymentAccepted {get;set;} 
        public Boolean isContactEmailAccepted {get;set;} 
        public Boolean isESignConsentAccepted {get;set;} 
        public Boolean isPreexistingConditionCoverageAccepted {get;set;} 
        public String lastName {get;set;} 
        public String leadSource {get;set;} 
        public String organizationId {get;set;} 
        public String policyTermId {get;set;} 
        public BillingAddress primaryAddress {get;set;} 
        public String primaryPhone {get;set;} 
        public String secondaryPhone {get;set;} 
        public Signature signature {get;set;} 
        public Transaction_Z transaction_Z {get;set;} // in json: transaction

        public Payload(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'additionalPolicyHolders') {
                            additionalPolicyHolders = arrayOfAdditionalPolicyHolders(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'animals') {
                            animals = arrayOfAnimals(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'billingAddress') {
                            billingAddress = new BillingAddress(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'deviceId') {
                            deviceId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'email') {
                            email = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'firstName') {
                            firstName = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'isAdvancePremiumPaymentAccepted') {
                            isAdvancePremiumPaymentAccepted = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else if (text == 'isContactEmailAccepted') {
                            isContactEmailAccepted = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else if (text == 'isESignConsentAccepted') {
                            isESignConsentAccepted = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else if (text == 'isPreexistingConditionCoverageAccepted') {
                            isPreexistingConditionCoverageAccepted = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else if (text == 'lastName') {
                            lastName = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'leadSource') {
                            leadSource = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'organizationId') {
                            organizationId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'policyTermId') {
                            policyTermId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'primaryAddress') {
                            primaryAddress = new BillingAddress(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'primaryPhone') {
                            primaryPhone = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'secondaryPhone') {
                            secondaryPhone = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'signature') {
                            signature = new Signature(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'transaction') {
                            transaction_Z = new Transaction_Z(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Payload consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String guid {get;set;} 
    public Payload payload {get;set;} 

    public Class_LeadExport(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'guid') {
                        guid = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'payload') {
                        payload = new Payload(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Class_LeadExport consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Diagnoses {
        public String examDate {get;set;} 
        public String medicalConditionDuration {get;set;} 
        public String medicalConditionId {get;set;} 
        public String medicalConditionResolutionDate {get;set;} 
        public String notes {get;set;} 
        public String veterinarianId {get;set;} 

        public Diagnoses(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'examDate') {
                            examDate = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'medicalConditionDuration') {
                            medicalConditionDuration = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'medicalConditionId') {
                            medicalConditionId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'medicalConditionResolutionDate') {
                            medicalConditionResolutionDate = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'notes') {
                            notes = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'veterinarianId') {
                            veterinarianId = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Diagnoses consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Transaction_Z {
        public String amount {get;set;} 
        public String amountAuthorized {get;set;} 
        public String authCode {get;set;} 
        public String avsResponse {get;set;} 
        public String customerVaultId {get;set;} 
        public String cvvResponse {get;set;} 
        public String orderId {get;set;} 
        public String response {get;set;} 
        public String responseCode {get;set;} 
        public String responseText {get;set;} 
        public String transactionId {get;set;} 
        public String type_Z {get;set;} // in json: type

        public Transaction_Z(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'amount') {
                            amount = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'amountAuthorized') {
                            amountAuthorized = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'authCode') {
                            authCode = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'avsResponse') {
                            avsResponse = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'customerVaultId') {
                            customerVaultId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'cvvResponse') {
                            cvvResponse = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'orderId') {
                            orderId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'response') {
                            response = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'responseCode') {
                            responseCode = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'responseText') {
                            responseText = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'transactionId') {
                            transactionId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'type') {
                            type_Z = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Transaction_Z consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static Class_LeadExport parse(String json) {
        System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        return new Class_LeadExport(parser);
    }

    public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }


    private static List<Diagnoses> arrayOfDiagnoses(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<Diagnoses> res = new List<Diagnoses>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new Diagnoses(p));
        }
        return res;
    }

    private static List<MedicalFiles> arrayOfMedicalFiles(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<MedicalFiles> res = new List<MedicalFiles>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new MedicalFiles(p));
        }
        return res;
    }


    private static List<AdditionalPolicyHolders> arrayOfAdditionalPolicyHolders(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<AdditionalPolicyHolders> res = new List<AdditionalPolicyHolders>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new AdditionalPolicyHolders(p));
        }
        return res;
    }

    private static List<Animals> arrayOfAnimals(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<Animals> res = new List<Animals>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new Animals(p));
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're supposed to use the `parse` method...not `Class_LeadExport exportClass = (Class_LeadExport)JSON.deserialize(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems like you have a ton of extra code all for the singular reason that your JSON has a reserved word as a member name.

### Option 1:

The easy solution is to use untyped deserialization:

```
Map<String, Object> payload = JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsondata)
```

this should be good enough. You can access anything the same way you would in a map:

```
Map<String, Object> transaction = (Map<String, Object>) payload.get('transaction');
String amount = (String) transaction.get('amount');
```

### Option 2

Pre-process the JSON to remove the reserved word from the JSON and then you can use deserialization to create your objects (credit: cropredy)

```
jsondata.replace('transaction', 'transaction_Z');
Class_LeadExport exportClass =
    (Class_LeadExport)JSON.deserialize(String.valueOf(jsondata), Class_LeadExport.class);
```

### Option 3

That being said, if you insist on continuing to use your custom classes, what Adrian said in the comments is correct, it should be

```
JSONParser jsonparser = JSON.createParser(jsondata);
Class_LeadExport exportClass = new Class_LeadExport(jsonparser);
```

Comment: or .. if possible, preprocess JSON (using String method `replace`) and convert reserved word attributes from `somereservedword` to `somereservedwordX` and then the deserialization is trivial into apex types

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Comment: All - thank you for the help, you all have saved me alot of time. I tried the simple fix with Option 3 and that seems to be working. Although in the future I will start with Option 1, very simple solution. Again -thank you all for your help!